# set a number of click and disable link from click after hit the target number

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, click, limit

I need to do setting for wordpress which set a number of clicks for some link to disable it after hit the targeted number. Is there any plugin or suggest to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple jQuery:

```
$('#targetLink').click(function () {
    $('#counter').html(function (i, val) {
        if (val > 1) {
            return val * 1 - 1;
        } else {
            $("#targetLink").removeAttr("href");
            if (val > 0) {
                return val * 1 - 1;
            }
        }
    }); });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/533L9n5f/

Of course, you have to adapt it to your HTML structure.

Next time, it could help a lot if you elaborate your question a bit more. Read this site for some best practices: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: thank you for your answer!:)
What if i need the link click counter countdown sync to every user. For example, countdown start from 10. After user A click on the link, the link countdown will become 9 and only 9 clicks are remain for other users. 

Hope you understand what i'm saying due to my poor english. :)
thanks.

Comment: The most reasonable option would be to make it server side. You can store the variable countdown in a database or a file, and get or modify its value depending on who clicked the link.